# Sending notification to GCM registrations using FCM console

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried sending notifications to GCM user using FCM console. But the notification delivered twice.

Is it possible to send notification to GCM registrations using FCM console.

Is there any way?

Comment: Don't know if that works, i think the Registration Tokens of GCM and FCM are not using the same pattern. So probably it won't work. Had problems with GCM since September, so i've migrated my project to FCM. No problems anymore